# is there any `backspace` character in mssql for string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, backspace

Below is the query to form a string containing company details by concatenating Name, address1 and address2. Here I am using the `ISNULL()` function to concatenate an empty string ('') if the column is null.

```
select Name+' ,'+isnull(Address1,'')+' ,'+isnull(Address2,'') as compDeatils 
from tableCompany where ID = 4
```

This query's issue is in the case where Address1 or Address2 is null, it will concatenate a comma before the empty space which I don't want.

For example, if Address1 and Address2 are NULL then the result will be `name,,`.

How i can overcome this?

*Is there a backspace character in mssql?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer it is simple logic.. `add commas within the ISNULL() function`

```
select Name+isnull(','+Address1,'')+isnull(','+Address2,'') as compDeatils 
from tableCompany where ID = 4
```

**Note**: Name will not give `NULL` in my case. in case name also null this answer is not applicable.

Comment: Doesn't quite do the correct thing if `Name` is null.

Comment: thats true.. but in my case, this is enough coz name will not allow null to insert.

Comment: Ok, then you can probably remove the ISNULL on `Name` too :)